# G-Drive Mobile external disk drive - should I use Firewire or USB 3.0?

Tags: mac, usb, storage, firewire

I have a [G-Technology G-Drive mobile 1TB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009733F08) with the option of either connecting via USB 3.0 or Firewire 800, which is the better choice for connecting with my MacBook Pro Early-2011? (In terms of speed or other considerations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in terms of speed, USB3 is far faster than Firewire.  USB3 transfers at 5 Gbit/s, while Firewire 800 is only 3200 Mbit/s.

USB does require more CPU overhead, but the loss is negligible.